# Seg fault with iterators and vectors

Tags: c++, vector

I seem to be having a problem displaying an item in a vector with an iterator. Possibly, I just need another set of eyes to look at it.

```
vector<string> tempVector;
vector<string>::iterator it;


it = tempVector.begin();
tempVector.push_back("1");
cout << *it;
```

I know this isn't the full code, but it's the only portion running. The output is a segfault. doesn't the iterator point to the beginning of the vector? I was expecting to get "1" to cout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `vector::reserve()` invalidates all existing iterators if it happens to require reallocation.

To quote the C++ standard, 23.3.6.3[vector.capacity]

> Reallocation happens at this point if and only if the current capacity is less than the argument of reserve().
>   [...]
>   Reallocation invalidates all the references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements in the sequence.

EDIT: After the edit, you have a call to `vector::push_back()`, which also invalidates all iterators if it requires reallocation. [Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) may be helpful.

Comment: @ChrisHarris, "invalidates all iterators" means if you try to use an iterator you created previously, you're likely to seg fault.